# Understanding an imperative list example in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am a newcomer to the ocaml.
appreciate if anyone can help me understand
the material presented on page 94 of the book
"developing applications with objective caml".

having trouble to grasp the meaning of the following paragraph:

> Just that the evaluation of `(itl l)` has taken place before the
>   evaluation of `(ihd l)`, so that on the last iteration of `imap`, the list referenced by `l`
>   became the empty list before we examined its head. The list example is henceforth
>   definitely empty even though we have not obtained any result

The `imap (function x ! x)` example returns

```
Uncaught exception: Failure("hd")
```

instead of

```
- : string ilist = {c=["one"; "two"; "three"]}
```

I would think that the

```
else icons (f (ihd l)) (imap f (itl l))`
```

would become `icons("one") ( ( icons("two") ( ( icon("three")([]) ) ) )`
and return

```
- : string ilist = {c=["one"; "two"; "three"]}
```

Answer (score 4):

I the example in the book, the list has been implemented in an imperative style.  The function `itl` mutates the list - that is it changes the list by removing the first element.  After the call to `itl`, the first element is essentially gone forever.

The tricky part is the order in which arguments to `icons` are executed in the statement:

```
else icons (f (ihd l)) (imap f (itl l))
```

In the OCaml spec the order isn't specified.  Last time I checked the INRIA compiler ordered the last argument first, so `(imap f (itl l))` is executed *before* `(f (ihd l))`.  What this means is that by the time `ihd` is actually called, `itl` has been called enough times to remove all the elements of `l`.

As an example, let's look at the penultimate recursive call - `l` is just `["three"]`.  You think that this would result in:

```
icons (f "three") (imap f [])
```

However let's look at what happens if we call `itl` first:

```
(* l = ["three"] *)
let tail = (itl l) in (* tail = [], l = [] *)
let head = (ihd l) in (* l = [], ihd raises an exception *)
icons head (imap f tail)
```

As an example, try running this code:

```
let f x y z = x + y + z
f (print_int 1; 1) (print_int 2; 2) (print_int 3; 3)
```

On my machine (OCaml 3.12) I get this output:

```
321- : int = 6
```